# Pass field title attribute through onchange another field

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code.

```js
//I want to pass field1 selected option's title through onkeyup
function select_data(field1) {
  alert(field1);
}
```

```html
<select id="field1" onchange="select_data(this.options[this.selectedIndex].title)">
  <option value="213" title="1">A</option>
  <option value="214" title="12">AB</option>
  <option value="215" title="13">AC</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="vat" onkeyup="select_data()" />
```

I want to get the selected option's title by onkeyup from text field.

Advance thanks for help.

Comment: Do you want to: select an option in the <select>, then when you type/keyup on the <input> what do you expect to happen?

Comment: @CalvinNunes I want select field's title, when onkeyup <input>

Comment: you want to set the option of the select when on keyup event?

Comment: @zb22 Nope, I want value of  title attribute from <select>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let selText = document.getElementById('field1').options[document.getElementById('field1').selectedIndex].title
```

Answer (score 1):

You want this:

```
<script>
//I want to pass field1 selected option's title through onkeyup
function select_data(field1) {
  //alert(field1);
  alert(field1.options[field1.selectedIndex].title);
}
</script>

<select id="field1" onchange="select_data(this.options[this.selectedIndex].title)">
  <option value="213" title="1">A</option>
  <option value="214" title="12">AB</option>
  <option value="215" title="13">AC</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="vat" onkeyup="select_data(document.querySelector('#field1'))" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by selecting the `select` inside of the function instead of passing all that parameter by inline HTML (which is not advisable). 
So, use `querySelector()` get the select, get the current selected index and title, show it.

THe below method can be called from everywhere and it will work, since all job of getting the title is inside the function

*Note:* Always when possible, avoid assing listeners in the HTML, it's not the right place and it is also obstrusive and not easy to maintain, opt for adding listeners in the JS/script part, also avoid passing parameters in HTML inline listeners.

```js
//I want to pass field1 selected option's title through onkeyup
function select_data() {
  let select = document.querySelector("#field1")
  let title = select.options[select.selectedIndex].title;
  console.log(title)
}
```

```html
<select id="field1" onchange="select_data()">
  <option value="213" title="1">A</option>
  <option value="214" title="12">AB</option>
  <option value="215" title="13">AC</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="vat" onkeyup="select_data()" />
```